# I have a two differnt array & i want to remove items in the second one that have the same property value of array1

Tags: arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, foreach

> inside the code $response['results'] is for google api. And $da is my databse records I am comparing these two using foreach on the basis of latitude of both data records. please help me out.

Here is my code :

```
$setarraymy= [];
      $setarray  = [];

        foreach($da as $data1){
            foreach ($response['results'] as $res){
              switch (true){

              case (round($data1['location']['lat'],4)!== round($res['geometry']
               ['location']['lat'],4) && !in_array($res['geometry']['location']['lat'],$setarray)):
               array_push($setarray,$res);
                break;

               case (!in_array($data1['location']['lat'],$setarraymy)):
               array_push($setarraymy,$data1);
                 break;

               default:
                 break;

          }
            }
              }
                echo json_encode(array( 'Results' =>$setarraymy,
                                         'status'=>'OK'),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                $new_array = array_unique($setarray, SORT_REGULAR);
                echo json_encode( array('Results'=>$new_array,
                                         'status'=>'OK'),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating array will be difficult, better to use collections and lastly convert collection to array as per your logic.

Avinash